# Url rewriting for Zeus - regex help

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, zeus

I've been landed with the unenviable task of putting a site live today only to find out its not running on Apache but instead is using Zeus. Now this breaks my mod_rewrite script rather messily.

Its a simple script which I've rewrote into Zeus format:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !404.php$ blog/404.php [L]
```

becomes

```
match URL into $ with ^/blog/(.*)           
if matched set URL=/blog/404.php
```

However, the downside is that whereas I turned mod_rewrite off in some of the child directories (eg css, images etc) I cant do this in Zeus.

Been playing around with regex to try and get the above regex to exclude any matches for /blog/css/ or /blog/images but no luck.

Hoping someone out there can help me out!

edit. currently working on this regex...

```
^(?=/blog/)((?!css/|images/|js/).)*$
```

So this should match any link with /blog/ in but exclude those with /blog/css, /blog/js and /blog/images. But it doesnt ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after trying lots of regex fanciness I went with KISS and came up with this. Hope it helps someone

```
 match URL into $ with ^/blog/(.*)$   
if matched 
match URL into $ with ^/blog/css/(.*)$
if not matched
match URL into $ with ^/blog/images/(.*)$
if not matched
match URL into $ with ^/blog/js/(.*)$
if not matched 
    set URL=/blog/404.php
endif
endif
endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of Zeus rewrites (I've never even heard of the product) but as long as there is no answer from an experienced user: According to [this blog post](http://www.pridedesign.ie/content/zeus-url-rewrite-rule-www), it is possible to nest rules in Zeus.

Something along these lines *might* work to turn off rewriting in /blog/css:

```
match URL into $ with ^/blog/css/(.*)           
if not matched 

  ... your 404 rewrite rule here

endif;
```

this is educated guesswork, but if I understand the syntax correctly it shoudln't be too far off.

Comment: That works and would exclude files within /blog/css but it catches every other file on the site. What I really need is a regex that matches any files within /blog/ except those within /blog/css/, /blog/images/ and /blog/js/